# Send commands to a socket with Python

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to connect to a socket file and send it some commands :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect("/var/run/socket")
s.send('a command here')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)
```

Did I miss something ?

I am totally new with Python.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Do you have a server program? Does your program raises an exception? What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what the actual problem is, or show any errors, but here are some things to check.

1. Firstly, does the socket actually exist?
2. Does your client python process have permission to access the socket file?
3. Is there a server process running that is listening for incoming connections on that socket?

Note that you need a client *and* a server for communication to take place. The server must already be running before the client can connect. The server creates the socket which must not already exist.

server.py

```
import os
import socket

address = '/tmp/socket'
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(address)      # this creates the socket file
s.listen(1)
r, a = s.accept()
r.send('Hello\n')
msg = r.recv(1024)
print msg
r.close()
s.close()
os.unlink(address)    # remove the socket file so that it can be recreated on next run
```

Run this server, then (in another terminal) run your client code:

client.py

```
import socket

server_addr = '/tmp/socket'
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(server_addr)
s.send('a command here')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)
```

Comment: Yes, the socket already exists (it is the haproxy socket) and I have permission to access this socket. I want to send some informations to the socket like 'show stats' 'show infos' and to print the result.

Comment: So, what is wrong then? Do you see any errors? You might need to send a new line after the command. Can you turn on logging/debugging on the server?